# SQL connect.php security risk?

Tags: php, sql, security

I'm just writing a PHP file to connect to my SQL server for a website login system and I'm terrified I'm just going to leave massive security holes.

I have my connect.php file in a directory of the websites root directory with this in it:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'publicguest', '**********', 'website');
```

where the password is open to see. I know when someone is looking at the website they cannot see the PHP code through the source but is this insecure and what is the common way to avoid this?

Comment: Posting anything on a web server is a risk. You're using a common method of connecting to your db. You should be fine.

Answer (score 3):

If your server has configuration issues, specifically php scripts aren't executed then someone may be able to get that info.
To avoid that you can put the file above the document root directory.

Comment: In the best case this information would useless as the credentials are only be valid when connecting from that specific machine.

Answer (score 3):

Unless they have direct access to the files you're working with, it should be fine.

Most commonly, people will store passwords and settings in a configuration file *above root level* which they then parse and use in those statements.  It will then be up to the attacker to reach that file.

If you **really** want to be obscure about it, you could encrypt those settings as well.

Answer (score 1):

Unless an attacker has FTP/direct access to the files, this is not a security risk as the PHP file is processed before outputting it to the client.

If the attacker has FTP/direct access, the mysql auth info is the least of the problems!

Wordpress stores the mysql login info in clear text in the wp-config.php, joomla does the same, there is no other way to do it i think.

Answer (score 1):

For a good practice you shouldn't use your password in the source code of your application, but rather store it in a db_config.php file outside your web root, making sure your config file is not publicly accessible.

This should get you deeper into the argument:
http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Securing_database_passwords

Answer (score 0):

For the most part its safe, unless:

For some reason your web server spits out your code in plaintext, this can happen in rare cases with server misconfiguration.

You can store your connection data outside of the web root to stop general access, but in the event a hacker has been allowed to execute PHP on your server for any reason, its game over anyways.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would change about that line of code is getting the username and password out of that particular line, eg:

```
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'publicguest';
$pass = 'hunter2';
$database = 'website';

$db = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);
```

The reason for this is if, at some point, your code encounters and error and spits out a stack trace it will not accidentally spit out your connection information as well.

If you *really* wants to be paranoid you can call:

```
unset($user);
unset($pass);
```

After the connection goes through, but that really only protects you from code injection, and so long as you *never ever use `eval()`* you should be fine. [seriously, never. `>:I`]

Anything further that people in this thread are suggesting is just paranoid faffing about because once someone has file-level access to your code they have the keys to your kingdom anyways and it's game over. But take heart! 99 times of 100 no one cares about your code or your database, they just want to inject their own code to send spam and/or DOS other people. `:P`